# How to bind grid view in special form

Tags: data-binding

I have a problem in grid view binding.I want to bind my grid view in special     form
    For Example:-

```
Class       Name         Address         phone no
 10         abc          australia       1233
            was          usa             56777
            qaz          uk              8766
 12         tre          india           64326
            yre          canada          76543
            poi          france          8566

I don't want to repeat same class more than once but show all student having same    class,so may you please tell me how i can do this work.

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: hmm...Not clear , but I think you are looking for ROWSPANing the gridview cells . ASP.net , C# , gridview ??

Comment: it's simple that for all class 10th and 12th students i don't want to display his\her class again and again in our grid view.Here 10 and 12 is just like a category and Name,Address and phone no is the data under that category and i don't want to repeat category again and again,if this thing is not possible in grid view then which data control i have to use.I hope that this time u will understand..